# Scroll Bar not Fully show the value In Div

Tags: html, css, asp.net

i am new to ASP.Net and CSS. In my application am split the main div to two part.
first part (`DivHeader`) is Fixed. second part have more text so the scroll bar But Not Showing Full Text.

My Tried: (Sample)

**CSS**

```
html,body
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
font-family: Trebuchet MS;
}

#DivMain
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:auto;
position:relative;
}
html,body
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
#DivMain
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:auto;
    position:relative;
 }
#DivHeader
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 155px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position:fixed ;
    z-index: 2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #00e5e6;
}
#DivBody  
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 750px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 155px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow:scroll;
    top: 4px;
    left: -2px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

**ASP.Net**

```
<div id="DivMain">
       <div id="DivHeader">
       </div>
       <div id="DivBody">
       <p>
       <br>fdf</br>
       sdf
       sd
       fas
       df
       asdf
       asd
       fas
       df
       asdf
       asd
       fd
       asf
       das
       fds
       f
       dasf
       das
       fdas
       f
         <br>fdf</br>  <br>fdf</br>
           <br>fdf</br>
             <br>fdf</br>
               <br>fdf</br>  <br>fdf</br>  <br>fdf</br>
                 <br>fdf</br>  <br>fdf</br>  <br>fdf</br>  <br>fdf</br>  <br>fdf</br>  <br>fdf</br>  <br>fdf</br>  <br>fdf</br>  <br>fdf</br>  <br>fdf</br>  <br>fdf</br>  <br>fdf</br>
       </p>
        </div>
        </div>
```

How to show full value in Div?

What am doing wrong here?

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8yLeb2xL/

Comment: is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/5mLtkgo1/

Comment: Am Changing My Question. Sorry for old...

Comment: remove position and overflow:scroll; for DivBody

Comment: @ArunKumarM Thanks... But how do scroll bar with bottom only.

Comment: @Sathish, checkout this https://jsfiddle.net/5mLtkgo1/1/

Comment: @ArunKumarM Thanks.. But i need bottom div only scroll with that space

Comment: @Sathish check this https://jsfiddle.net/8yLeb2xL/4/

Comment: Thanks @ArunKumarM. Can you change as answer

Comment: @Sathish Added as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8yLeb2xL/12/)**

```
html,body
{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   padding:0px;
   margin:0px;
   font-family: Trebuchet MS;
}
#DivMain
{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#DivHeader
{
   width: 100%;
   height: 120px; 
   border-bottom:1px solid gray;
}
#DivBody  
{
   width: 100%;
   height:calc(100% - 121px);
}
#DivBodyChild {
   height:100%;
   overflow-y:scroll;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Position `fixed` to `absolute`

```
 #DivBody  
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 750px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 155px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow:scroll;
    top: 4px;
    left: -2px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8yLeb2xL/3/

Comment: But my Top is fixed.

Comment: Now Changed My question. Top Fixed. Second part Scroll. But Now not showing full text in second part.